# Nginx not using the configured index page

Tags: nginx

I have a simple SPA app running in an Nginx container with the following configuration:

```nginx
server {
    listen   8080;
    listen   [::]:8080 default ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    server_name _; # all hostnames

    location / {
        try_files $uri /404.html;
    }
}
```

When I run the container on port 44811 I can browse to my index page at http://localhost:44811/index.html and other files are served as expected. If I try any URI that doesn't match a hosted file path then I see my `404.html` page. However the root path (http://localhost:44811/) also shows the 404. Why doesn't it show the `index.html` as per my config?

Here's a view of the container's file system:

[image]